# Unifying Mouse Update from Ubuntu Software: { RQR12.11_B0032 }

Tags: software-installation, keyboard, mouse, software-center, mousepad

I, too, have Logitech combination Keyboard with mouse.  Never installed this, and it does not show as an installed product from from within Ubuntu Software.
This, logically, is operating like an anomaly and makes me question the security of installing it.
Please advise.  Everything on my system seems to be working fine without this product, and if it is a system component, why doesn't it upgrade with Software Update like all other system software?